# Tabulator - how to call a function when using the built in "list" editor and selecting a list option

Tags: editor, tabulator

I'm new to Tabulator. When using the built in list editor on a column, how would I call a function when one of the list items is selected and get the value of the newly selected list item? I've tried cellClick but it calls the function before I can select an item and cellEdited doesn't fire when the item is selected. Any ideas? Thanks!

Here is the column setup:
{title:"Status", field:"status", editor:"list", editorParams:{values:{"Active":"Active", "Won":"Won", "Lost":"Lost", "Cancelled":"Cancelled"}},cellEdited:function(e, cell){CallSomeFunction(cell);}

Comment: Follow up correction - cellEdited does fire but cell.getValue() does not work.